# Parsing JSON from URL and getting values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Get JSON from URL - Test</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1-rc2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="testjson"></p>

<script>
  var bpAPI = "http://backpack.tf/api/IGetPrices/v4/?key=55b0c2a2ba8d88e10a8b45a6";

  $.getJSON(bpAPI, function(json) {
    document.getElementById("testjson").innerHTML = "Price: " + json.response.items['A Brush with Death'].prices['6'].Tradable.Craftable['0'].value;
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

After solving my previous problem, I've encountered another one. I was trying to load JSON from URL and then getting values I wanted. The thing is, that my code doesn't seem to work. All I got was an empty page.

Comment: and what is shown in your console? Did you try to debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting your code into [this codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/bVbbmo), I got it to work fine once I started using [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to fetch the data. This means that you were having a cross origin domain issue.

Using JSONP with this code is as simple as adding callback=? to the url:

```
var bpAPI = "http://backpack.tf/api/IGetPrices/v4/?key=55b0c2a2ba8d88e10a8b45a6&callback=?";
```

Be weary though, there are known security concerns with using JSONP

Also, the service you are using seems pretty slow, on my connection it took 5.77 seconds to load the response, so it may take a little bit of time for you to see it show up